# Webpage navigation not appearing correctly

Tags: html, css, navigation, styling

I'm having problems with my webpage navigation bar and I would like to know the correct way I should be approaching this. Currently the navigation on the right is appearing in the line below. I have tried to get this working correctly by using float: right but I know float can cause a heap of issues.

```
    <div class="subHeading">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Your account</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Our services</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Your water</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Get help</a></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="css/images/icon_search_border.png"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

http://codepen.io/s_bruno1/pen/GrYpKb

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the part your trying to solve the "Your account Our services Your water Get help" that is floating above the box?

Comment: Hi Ronnie, yes it is. Hopefully from the Codepen you will be able to see that the navigation is moving into the main blue header section when this should in fact be separated (with some gap in between the main header and the navigation just above it).

I thought about using <br> but haven't tested this yet, nor am I sure whether this is the best method to use?

Comment: Could you please take a look at this image https://gyazo.com/01e8c7e972b711b72b10db86b584fd13
and tell me if this is what you need?

Comment: Hi Ronnie, ideally I want something like this please: 

https://s28.postimg.org/470tzbx3x/nav.png